# How routing works in Express with optional parameters?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

At the moment I've routing like this:

```
app.get('/post/:id?/:edit?/:add?') // ... func and something else
```

When I'm sending query to url `'/post/'`, without parameters, it retrieves all posts.

On `'/post/5'`, where 5 is id of post, it retrieves post with id 5 in db.

On `'/post/5/edit'`, opens page with form, for editing current post.

Everything is good. But when I'm trying to open `'post/add/`, it didn't work., because `req.params` shows in console that: `id: 'add', edit: undefined, add: undefined`.
How to fix it?

Comment: So I think this is an issue of putting to much functionality into one route. Each of those functions (get, edit, add) should have there own route. Otherwise you are putting way to much overhead into that single route function. Additionally for the edit and add you should be using POST requests (or if you're really fancy PUT & POST)

Comment: Thanks, most likely I will do it.

Answer (score 0):

req.params are basically an array, so in your case the first parameter, req.params[0], will always be req.params.id, whatever value you provide, and your programm will think you're trying to retrieve a post with id 'add'.

You might want to make 'post/add' a separate route, it'll be easier.